# Calculating and plotting count ratios with Pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have multidimensional data in a pandas data frame with one variable indicating class. For example here is my attempt with a poor-maps heatmap scatter plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap

nrows=1000
df=pd.DataFrame([[random.random(), random.random()]+[random.randint(0, 1)] for _ in range(nrows)],
                 columns=list("ABC"))

bins=np.linspace(0, 1, 20)           
df["Abin"]=[bins[i-1] for i in np.digitize(df.A, bins)]
df["Bbin"]=[bins[i-1] for i in np.digitize(df.B, bins)]

g=df.ix[:,["Abin", "Bbin"]+["C"]].groupby(["Abin", "Bbin"])
data=g.agg(["sum", "count"])
data.reset_index(inplace=True)
data["classratio"]=data[("C", "sum")]/data[("C","count")]

plt.scatter(data.Abin, data.Bbin, c=data.classratio, cmap=get_cmap("RdYlGn_r"), marker="s")
```

I'd like to plot class densities over binned features. Now I used `np.digitize` for binning and some complicating Python hand-made density calculation to plot a heatmap.

Surely, this can be done more compactly with Pandas (pivot?)? Do you know a neat way to bin the two features (for example 10 bins on the interval 0...1) and then plot a class density heatmap where color indicates the ratio of 1's to total rows within this 2D-bin?

Comment: Can you show us what you expect and the code you tried so far ?

Comment: You're sort of saying: "How can I do 'xyz' more simply with pandas?" but it's not quite clear what exactly 'xyz' is... Also, as far as plotting goes, do any of the plots [here](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) look close to what you're shooting for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, it can be done in a very concise way using the build in `cut` function:

In [65]:

```
nrows=1000
df=pd.DataFrame([[random.random(), random.random()]+[random.randint(0, 1)] for _ in range(nrows)],
                 columns=list("ABC"))
In [66]:
#This does the trick.
pd.crosstab(np.array(pd.cut(df.A, 20)), np.array(pd.cut(df.B, 20))).values
Out[66]:
array([[2, 2, 2, 2, 7, 2, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 7, 2, 4, 2],
       [1, 2, 4, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1],
       [0, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 5, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 6, 5, 2, 2],
       [5, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 4, 0, 3, 2, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3],
       [2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 4, 0],
       [2, 3, 3, 5, 2, 0, 5, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 6, 4],
       [3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 0, 0, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 6, 4, 2, 0, 5, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2],
       [3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4],
       [0, 1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 1, 4],
       [2, 2, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 2, 1, 4, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 2, 0, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0],
       [3, 3, 0, 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 5, 7, 2],
       [3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 5, 6, 1, 3, 2, 2],
       [3, 0, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 3, 2, 2, 4, 3, 0, 2],
       [0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 5, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
       [1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 5, 5, 1, 0, 1, 0, 4, 3, 3, 2],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 6, 5, 2, 5, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 0],
       [3, 3, 4, 7, 0, 2, 6, 4, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2],
       [3, 6, 3, 4, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 1, 6, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 0, 4]])
In [67]:

abins=np.linspace(df.A.min(), df.A.max(), 21)
bbins=np.linspace(df.B.min(), df.B.max(), 21)
Z=pd.crosstab(np.array(pd.cut(df.ix[df.C==1, 'A'], abins)), 
            np.array(pd.cut(df.ix[df.C==1, 'B'], bbins)), aggfunc=np.mean).div(
            pd.crosstab(np.array(pd.cut(df.A, abins)), 
                        np.array(pd.cut(df.B, bbins)), aggfunc=np.mean)).values
Z = np.ma.masked_where(np.isinf(Z),Z)
x=np.linspace(df.A.min(), df.A.max(), 20)
y=np.linspace(df.B.min(), df.B.max(), 20)
X,Y=np.meshgrid(x, y)
plt.contourf(X, Y, Z, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

```
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the `cut` and heatmap suggestion! Though, it seems `crosstab` isn't doing the right thing? For each bin I want to plot the ratio between 1's and the total points *within this bin*. That's why I divide `sum/count`. That's different from `crosstab`? Is there a concise solution with `pivot`?

Comment: Sorry for miss understood your question. Sure, you can do it with a similar approach, only 0/0 will result in `inf`, and we need to use a masked array to deal with that. see the updated edit.