# Extending numpy.digitize to multi-dimensional data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, binning

I have a set of large arrays (about 6 million elements each) that I want to basically perform a np.digitize but over multiple axes.  I am looking for some suggestions on both how to effectively do this but also on how to store the results.

I need all the indices (or all the values, or a mask) of array A where the values of array B are in a range and the values of array C are in another range and D in yet another.  I want either the values, indices, or mask so that I can do some as of yet undecided statistics on the values of the A array in each bin.  I will also need the number of elements in each bin but `len()` can do that.

Here is one example I worked up that seems reasonable:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

A = np.random.random_sample(1e4)
B = (np.random.random_sample(1e4) + 10)*20
C = (np.random.random_sample(1e4) + 20)*40
D = (np.random.random_sample(1e4) + 80)*80

# make the edges of the bins
Bbins = np.linspace(B.min(), B.max(), 10)
Cbins = np.linspace(C.min(), C.max(), 12) # note different number
Dbins = np.linspace(D.min(), D.max(), 24) # note different number

B_Bidx = np.digitize(B, Bbins)
C_Cidx = np.digitize(C, Cbins)
D_Didx = np.digitize(D, Dbins)

a_bins = []
for bb, cc, dd in itertools.product(np.unique(B_Bidx), 
                                    np.unique(C_Cidx), 
                                    np.unique(D_Didx)):
    a_bins.append([(bb, cc, dd), [A[np.bitwise_and((B_Bidx==bb),
                                                   (C_Cidx==cc),
                                                   (D_Didx==dd))]]])
```

This however makes me nervous that I will run out of memory on large arrays.

I could also do it this way:

```
b_inds = np.empty((len(A), 10), dtype=np.bool)
c_inds = np.empty((len(A), 12), dtype=np.bool)
d_inds = np.empty((len(A), 24), dtype=np.bool)
for i in range(10):
    b_inds[:,i] = B_Bidx = i     
for i in range(12):
    c_inds[:,i] = C_Cidx = i     
for i in range(24):
    d_inds[:,i] = D_Didx = i     
# get the A data for the 1,2,3 B,C,D bin
print A[b_inds[:,1] & c_inds[:,2] & d_inds[:,3]]
```

At least here the output is of known and constant size.

Does anyone have any better thoughts on how to do this smarter?  Or clarification that is needed?

---

Based on the answer by HYRY this is the path I decided to take.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
A =  np.random.random_sample(1e7)
B = (np.random.random_sample(1e7) + 10)*20
C = (np.random.random_sample(1e7) + 20)*40
D = (np.random.random_sample(1e7) + 80)*80
# make the edges of the bins we want
Bbins = np.linspace(B.min(), B.max(), 9)
Cbins = np.linspace(C.min(), C.max(), 10) # note different number
Dbins = np.linspace(D.min(), D.max(), 11) # note different number
sA = pd.Series(A)
cB = pd.cut(B, Bbins, include_lowest=True)
cC = pd.cut(C, Cbins, include_lowest=True)
cD = pd.cut(D, Dbins, include_lowest=True)

dat = pd.DataFrame({'A':A, 'cB':cB.labels, 'cC':cC.labels, 'cD':cD.labels})
g = sA.groupby([cB.labels, cC.labels, cD.labels]).indices
# this then gives all the indices that match the group 
print g[0,1,2]
# this is all the array A data for that B,C,D bin
print sA[g[0,1,2]]
```

This method seems lightning fast even for huge arrays.

Comment: Here is a post of similar problem in 2D situation, see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613166/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about use `groupby` in Pandas. Fix some problem in your code first:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

A = np.random.random_sample(1e4)
B = (np.random.random_sample(1e4) + 10)*20
C = (np.random.random_sample(1e4) + 20)*40
D = (np.random.random_sample(1e4) + 80)*80

# make the edges of the bins
Bbins = np.linspace(B.min(), B.max(), 10)
Cbins = np.linspace(C.min(), C.max(), 12) # note different number
Dbins = np.linspace(D.min(), D.max(), 24) # note different number

B_Bidx = np.digitize(B, Bbins)
C_Cidx = np.digitize(C, Cbins)
D_Didx = np.digitize(D, Dbins)

a_bins = []
for bb, cc, dd in itertools.product(np.unique(B_Bidx), 
                                    np.unique(C_Cidx), 
                                    np.unique(D_Didx)):
    a_bins.append([(bb, cc, dd), A[(B_Bidx==bb) & (C_Cidx==cc) & (D_Didx==dd)]])

a_bins[1000]
```

output:

```
[(4, 6, 17), array([ 0.70723863,  0.907611  ,  0.46214047])]
```

Here is the code that return the same result by Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

cB = pd.cut(B, 9)
cC = pd.cut(C, 11)
cD = pd.cut(D, 23)

sA = pd.Series(A)
g = sA.groupby([cB.labels, cC.labels, cD.labels])
g.get_group((3, 5, 16))
```

output:

```
800     0.707239
2320    0.907611
9388    0.462140
dtype: float64
```

If you want to calculate some statistics of every group, you can call the method of `g`, for example:

```
g.mean()
```

returns:

```
0  0  0     0.343566
      1     0.410979
      2     0.700007
      3     0.189936
      4     0.452566
      5     0.565330
      6     0.539565
      7     0.530867
      8     0.568120
      9     0.587762
      11    0.352453
      12    0.484903
      13    0.477969
      14    0.484328
      15    0.467357
...
8  10  8     0.559859
       9     0.570652
       10    0.656718
       11    0.353938
       12    0.628980
       13    0.372350
       14    0.404543
       15    0.387920
       16    0.742292
       17    0.530866
       18    0.389236
       19    0.628461
       20    0.387384
       21    0.541831
       22    0.573023
Length: 2250, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have heard of Pandas but never used it before.  I will spend a few minutes with this answer and see how it feels.

Comment: Can you comment on the performance of Pandas vs. Numpy in this use case? Is one code faster than the other, or is one more memory efficient, or is one more user-friendly? Thanks.