# Two-dimensional np.digitize

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, binning

I have two-dimensional data and I have a bunch of two-dimensional bins generated with `scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d`.   For each data point, I want the index of the bin it occupies.  This is exactly what `np.digitize` is for, but as far as I can tell, it only deals with one-dimensional data.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643229/extending-numpy-digitize-to-multi-dimensional-data) stackexchange seems to have an answer, but that is totally generalized to n-dimensions.  Is there a more straightforward solution for two dimensions?

Comment: whoops! yep! thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

You can already get the bin index of each observation from the fourth return variable of [`scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html):

> ```
> Returns:  
>   statistic : (nx, ny) ndarray
>       The values of the selected statistic in each two-dimensional bin.
>   xedges : (nx + 1) ndarray
>       The bin edges along the first dimension.
>   yedges : (ny + 1) ndarray
>       The bin edges along the second dimension.
>   binnumber : (N,) array of ints or (2,N) ndarray of ints
>       This assigns to each element of sample an integer that
>       represents the bin in which this observation falls. The
>       representation depends on the expand_binnumbers argument.
>       See Notes for details.
> ```

Comment: With the option `expand_binnumbers=True` (new in version 0.17.0) the binnumber meaning changes ([see doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html)) making it more easy to use depending on the application.

Answer (score 2):

a simple solution using numpy:

```
bins = [[0.3, 0.5, 0.7], [0.3, 0.7]]
values = np.random.random((10, 2))
digitized = []
for i in range(len(bins)):
    digitized.append(np.digitize(values[:, i], bins[i], right=False))
digitized = np.concatenate(digitized).reshape(10, 2)
```