# Calculate Mean and StandardDeviation in Histogram2d bins

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have created a histogram2d grid in python numpy and plotted some values in each grid cell. I want to calculate how many points go into each cell along with its mean and standard deviation. How can I achieve that one?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163334/binning-data-in-python-with-scipy-numpy

Comment: The link which you have mentioned has digitized method information but it only works along with histogram as it has a 1D array. But in my case, it's a 2D data.

Comment: That was meant for you to get an understanding what to look for. For example seaching for "digitize 2D" yields https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635265/two-dimensional-np-digitize