# numpy digitize for 2 dimensional histogram

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, histogram, histogram2d

I am searching for the `np.digitize` function for bi-dimensional histogram.

From these lines of code:

```
    H, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(coord[:, 0], coord[:, 1])
    H = H.T
    print(H)
```

I obtain the following histogram:

```
[[ 7. 20. 16. 14. 10.  8. 16.  7. 10.  7.]
 [11. 11. 10. 10.  5. 10.  9. 12.  7.  7.]
 [13. 11. 13.  9. 13. 10. 14.  6.  9.  9.]
 [ 5.  5.  4.  5.  7. 13. 14. 11.  6. 10.]
 [14.  4. 11.  5.  7. 14.  6. 11. 11.  5.]
 [12.  9.  5.  7.  9. 14. 15. 15. 13. 12.]
 [ 5. 13. 15.  9. 10.  7. 10. 12.  7.  5.]
 [ 4. 10. 15.  7.  6. 10. 13.  5. 12. 12.]
 [12.  6. 11.  8.  5.  5. 13. 14. 13.  9.]
 [10. 11.  9.  8. 18. 13. 16.  8.  8. 13.]]
```

and I want to find out indices that each element of histogram represents, e.g. (1st row, 1st column -> 7 -> 7 indices should be computed).
I spent many hours trying to follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643229/extending-numpy-digitize-to-multi-dimensional-data), but I get stuck at one place (I can explain where, if no better approach is known). Another potential duplicate is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635265/two-dimensional-np-digitize?noredirect=1&lq=1) but this also does not solve the problem.

So does anybody know, how to resolve this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d.html):

```
H, xedges, yedges, binnumber = scipy.stats.binned_statistic_2d(
    coord[:, 0], coord[:, 1], None, 'count', expand_binnumbers=True)
```

The first three return values are the same as your original code.  The fourth (`binnumber`)` is:

> a shape (2,N) ndarray, where each row gives the bin numbers in the corresponding dimension.